# Honda Car Door Leather Tear and Restoration

Tags: damage, restoration, leather

I have a Honda with leather interior. Recently, there was an incident while carrying stuff in my car and the leather on the door got torn because of that.

Here is a link to the pictures of the damage - https://gist.github.com/dev-usa/9c2615fff2e327bd7f06ab578586b0c2#file-carimages-html

This is my first time handling a repair for leather and also something that involves a car, could you please advise what steps I can take to fix this?

I tried looking around for some guidance and have seen some leather restoration videos and blogs, but I am not sure if that would work for a Honda leather door.

I am posting my question here after some research to be sure than sorry after attempting a repair.

Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: Find a replacement from a scrap car... as you won’t hide that - only saw your first image though as it marks the others as too large.

Answer (score 0):

While it is difficult to tell from your photos it is likely the door panel is trimmed with vinyl not leather. With the exception of a few high-end models most vehicles with a "leather" interior have leather on the seating surface only. You have three choices. Have the panel replaced with either a new panel (expensive) or a used panel at likely 1/2 the cost of new. See if an automotive upholstery shop can repair it. You can also try to repair it yourself. Most automotive parts suppliers sell vinyl/leather repairs kits. The kit contains a clear adhesive (some also contains small amounts of dyes to color match) and a small pad to emboss a pattern if needed. From what I can see the tear is small so even a decent quality repair is likely to be obvious only under very close inspection or by you because you know it is there.

Comment: you may be right in saying that it is vinyl. I am so novice with this stuff that I have no way to differentiate between leather and vinyl. Also, by mentioning about repair kits - is it similar to the one in the video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ji-PgX32210 ?

Comment: The kit shown is exactly what I had in mind.

Comment: How to tell leather from vinyl. Vinyl has threads and fibers in it. The real test is carefully hold a small flame near an edge, if it melts/catches fire it's NOT leather.